# Timeline: Duplicate of .. what?

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, timeline

When a question is closed as duplicate, then reopened and no edit was made to the question, we have no way to know who reopened the question and what was the duplicate target unless we do a trivial edit to access the revisions or we use the timeline.

Even in the Timeline some information are missing such as the duplicate target:

> [image]

We can see that the question is closed as duplicate of .. nothing.

There is a lot of way to find the information like the "Linked" tab and the edits but the above seems to a bug and it would be good if we can add the missing information there.

Worth to note that the same is happening on Meta

Comment: "*There is a lot of way to find the information like the "Linked" tab*" but that's not necessarily reliable. There might have been multiple links posted and deleted, so the Linked tab will show all of them, not just the one that was used as a dupe target. So, we definitely need a reliable way to find the last duplicate target

Comment: FWIW, edit to the list of duplicates will be marked as `<date> — <history> — <user> — "duplicates list edited" — "from <question-id1> to <question-id1>,<question-id2>"` (here an other target was added).

Comment: @Kaiido and it would be good to make the ID as links in that case because it's not funny to build the link alone doing some copy/paste

Comment: Another: [The thin expanding blue line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395985/7296893)

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395982/do-our-own-accepted-answers-to-our-questions-get-counted-for-the-unsung-hero-and

Comment: @Erik this seems to be a serious new bug, the last two questions on meta closed as duplicate are showing the same thing (not related to this one by the way)

Comment: @Rob this seems to be fixed, I think we can make it status-completed.

Comment: Just an unrelated note: you can access any post's revisions without any edit by visiting `https://<meta.>stackoverflow.com/posts/<post-id>/revisions`... For this post, it is [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/393107/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/393107/revisions)

Comment: Announced as fixed by Yaakov Ellis [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345859).