# The thin expanding blue line

Tags: bug, survey, banner

The new take a survey banner:

[image]

Will pop back up if the page is refreshed, and then immediately goes away, but it leaves a small blue bar behind. Every time you refresh the page, the bar gets a bit bigger

First refresh:

[image]

Second:

[image]

Tenth:

[image: ban]

---

After more analysis, I've found that what is happening is the page is scrolling down, and that is why I though the banner disappeared. If you scroll up after the first refresh, you'll see the full banner. Can we get it to stay gone once dismissed?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like there's a bug with self-accepting duplicates not showing up.

Comment: @TylerH It's strange.  Didn't happen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396000/short-survey-banner-refuses-to-go-away) so not sure if it is still an issue or not.