# Question marked as duplicate with no dupe target

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936341/rust-how-do-you-alter-a-variables-value-from-within-a-for-loop) as a duplicate last week. The OP agreed with the close vote and the question was closed by the Community user.

However, the close notice does not link to the question it was marked as a duplicate of ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40323500/3650362)). Instead, the list of duplicate questions is empty:

[image: dupe notice containing no question links]

The dupe target is still linked in the sidebar, but not in the notice or the question comments.

[Timeline: Duplicate of .. what?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393107/timeline-duplicate-of-what) looks similar, but describes missing information on a question that has been reopened. This question is still closed as a duplicate, just with no target. However, the comments on that question link to [The thin expanding blue line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395985/the-thin-expanding-blue-line), which appears to show the same bug on Meta.

Comment: I saw this a while ago here on Meta - I've been waiting for a second observation to confirm. This happens when Community closes the question (as in OP self-hammers the question with the "yes, this answers my question" button). This is indeed a bug

Comment: How comes there is no comment on that question linking to the duplicate? That's what usually happens - was it deleted?

Comment: @AndrewMorton questions to the dupe target are always deleted when the question is closed as a duplicate, unless the comment is modified I think? Or the question isn't closed as a duplicate, of course.

Comment: This one has also been [reported on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty). [Yaakov Ellis is working on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty#comment1159009_345859).